# How to make a cumulative sequence?

Tags: clojure, cumulative-sum

Say I have a lazy sequence like the following:

```
(def s (iterate inc 1))
(take 10 s)
=> (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
```

Now, I want to generate a sequence of cumulative sum of `s` like the following:

```
=> (1 3 6 10 15 ...)
```

How can I do this?
What I tried is to use `atom` and accumulate the sum to it(mutating) Is this the only way to generate cumulative sequence or is there a better way to do this?

NOTE: the above cumulative sum is only an example. The source sequence can be other sequence. So I can't use formula: `s(n) = n(n+1)/2`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
(take 10 (reductions + s))
=> (1 3 6 10 15 21 28 36 45 55)
```